# Partial Line Code Coverage in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, code-coverage

I hit a problem about code coverage measurement in .NET Tool (CodeCoverage.exe)
Below is my code:

```
public static void test1(int a)
{
    if (a > 0 && a < 3)
    {
        Console.Write("Hello world");
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

I try with test cases such as

Case 1:

```
test1(1); true - true
test1(-4); false - true
```

Result is above code is full coverage. But with test case:

Case 2:

```
test1(1); true - true
test1(5); true - false
```

Result is above code is partial coverage.
Do you explain difference between case 1 and case 2? I think that both case are cover branch If-Else
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Case 1 - Only first condition is evaluated, it does not have to evaluate second one.
Case 2 - as first condition is true, the second condition has to be evaluated.

Comment: I see. But I would like to know why result of Case 2 is partial coverage without full coverage.I follow to microsoft but it seem incorrect https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/dd299398(v=vs.90)

Comment: I suppose that it's the metter of border testing. I'm wondering what would show test coverage if you add test1(0) and test1(3). In fact you should test border conditions.

Answer (score 0):

I see. But I would like to know why result of Case 2 is partial coverage without full coverage.I follow to microsoft but it seem incorrect learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/… –